# Necessary and sufficient condition of $F,G$ for the existence of $f$ such that $\text{Im}\,f=F$ and $\ker{f}=G$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $E$ a $K$ vector space, and $F,G$ two subspaces.

Find the necessary and sufficient condition on $F,G$ for the existence of $f \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $Im f=F$ and $\ker f=G$.

I'm stuck on this problem. I would answer $F\cap G =\{0\} $ but, I can't show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you suggested isn't true. For a counter-example, take $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $f(e_1)=0$ and $f(e_2)=e_1$, where $e_1,e_2$ are any two linearly independent vectors in $E$.

To find the correct answer, use the rank-nullity theorem:

> Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$ and $f\in\mathcal{L}(E)$. Then:$$\dim{E}=\dim\ker{f}+\dim\text{Im}\,f$$

Comment: Thank your. So, a necessary condition is : $\dim{G} + \dim{F} = \dim E$, but is it a sufficient condition too?

Comment: @MiKiDe Yes it is! Give it a try ;)

Comment: @MiKiDe A small remark concerning LaTeX: you can write \dim{G} to get $\dim{G}$. That's more good looking ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (and your latex tip :) )! I finally did it!

Comment: @MiKiDe Glad you did it! Good job (y). Unrelated, but a small text recommendation: *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler. I read it entirely, with exercises :) The author's approach is pretty unique; not good for a first course, especially that it doesn't focus on matrices, determinants, other computational stuff and no mention of bilinear and quadratic forms, but it's a GREAT book for understanding the theory in an intuitive manner. If I was able to give you this answer so quickly, it's due to the exercises on this book :)

Comment: I keep it in mind, but I'm not use to english mathematics so it may be hard for me :)

Comment: @MiKiDe I see. Well, if you're willing to pursue your studies in mathematics (or maybe any other science), you should get used to math in english. It seems you're still in your first or second year, so it's not too late for it ;) Actually, in my country, Morocco, we don't study anything in English (except the language itself) before and after high school, but with practice (reading lessons and doing exercises on english textbooks), you get used to it (in fact, I started to prefer doing math in english than in the other language (that isn't our native language anyway))...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55592/discussion-between-mikide-and-scientifica).